# how is 1 tar split into several archives extracted as 1 full archive

Tags: tar

So I've never done this before with the actual tar command windows: easy select all three extract here,  Linux probably something similar. but I'm using a system that cant do that, so I need the command for extracting multiple split tars as one. Tried tar -xvf file.tar file.tar file.tar but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

answer: $ cat filenamewithoutpartnumberorextension* > file.tar